# Error using commands.Greedy in Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: discord, discord.py

Whenever I try to use `commands.Greedy` I keep get `AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'Greedy'`. Here's my code:

```
@client.command(description="Kicks user", usage="[@user(s)]", brief="Kicks user")
@commands.has_role(settings.admin_role_name)
async def kick(self, ctx, targets: commands.Greedy[discord.Member], *reason: str):
    for target in targets:
        await target.kick(reason="{} ({}) used .kick command with the reason {}".format(ctx.message.author.name, ctx.message.author.id, reason))
        await ctx.send("<@{}> kicked <@{}>\n**Reason:** {}".format(ctx.message.author.id, target.id, reason))

@client.command(description="Bans user", usage="[@user]", brief="Bans user")
@commands.has_role(settings.admin_role_name)
async def ban(self, ctx, targets: commands.Greedy[discord.Member], *reason: str):
    for target in targets:
        await target.ban(reason="{} ({}) used .kick command with the reason {}".format(ctx.message.author.name, ctx.message.author.id, reason))
        await ctx.message.channel.send("{} banned <@{}>\n**Reason:** {}".format(ctx.message.author.id, target.id, reason))
```

My discord version is discord.py    1.0.0a1561+g53433bc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled discord.py, turns out I had a old version that didn't have [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/commit/814b03f5a8a6faa33d80495691f1e1cbdce40ce2)